# Django: "Could not import settings 'blog.settings'"

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. I was getting this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I decided to define the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable.

(*My project location:
`C:\DjangoProjects\blog`*)

I added `C:\DjangoProjects` (*parent folder of the project*) to the `PYTHONPATH`.  In my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable I have `blog.settings`.

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'blog.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named blog.settings
```

*The `settings` file has no errors.*

What's wrong with this?

Comment: How do you run server? Did you change anything in settings?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works in the same way in Windows as Unix, but is there a file called __init__.py in your blog directory?

Comment: \__init__.py* didn't realize two underscores creates bold in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Do not touch `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, revert to the original value. You need to set properly `DATABASES` dictionary, at least  `'default'` key - ENGINE -> what kind of database backend you are using, username/password for the database access, name of the database etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be your `PYTHONPATH`. If your project is at `C:\DjangoProjects\blog` (meaning that the settings file is at `C:\DjangoProjects\blog\blog\settings.py`), then your `PYTHONPATH` should point to `C:\DjangoProjects\blog`, not just `C:\DjangoProjects`.